# For loop through an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am trying to write a for loop to iterate from a specific index range.

So if a I have an array called `data[]` with length 10, and I only want to iterate from the 3rd position (index 2) to the 9th position (index 8), how could I go about writing that loop structure?

The sample code is below:

```
//Trying to iterate from index 2 - 9
for(int i=0; i<data.length && i>2 && i<9; i++)
{
    System.out.println(data[i]);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: for(int i = 2 i < data.length - 2; i++)

Comment: Slow down and go through some tutorials. Your for loop has a few syntax errors.

Comment: Don't use an array. Use a `List` and `for(Data d : list.subList(start, end){`.

Comment: If he doesn't even know how to use a simple for-loop, I doubt lists are the thing to look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the start index & the stop index of your for loop. So the breaking condition of your for lop would be if index (i) becomes greater than or equal to 9 or greater than or equal the length of the array.

```
for(int i = 2;  i < 9 && i < data.length;  i++)
{
  System.out.println(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: "greater than 9" should be "greater than or equal to 9".  Also "greater than the length of the array" should be "greater than or equal to ...".

Answer (score 3):

Just write:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
for(int i=2; i<data.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(data[i]);
}
```

If the length is fixed(9):

```
for(int i=2; i<= 9; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
```

You can do it like:
This will iterate the loop from 3rd position to the last index.

Comment: And you also forgot a `<9`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The length of array is 10, it can vary.. So for general purpose i kept that.

Comment: But he wanted that range

Comment: The OP says the iteration from be from `3` (index `2`) to `9` (index `8`). It's quite explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code definitely isn't valid but I guess it's just a typo. Typically you want this:

```
for(int i=2 ; i < Math.min(9,data.length) ; ++i)
{
    System.out.println(data[i]);
}
```

I recommend to use `Math.min(8,data.length)` instead of simply `8` just in case your array has less than 9 elements.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's always good practice to make sure you don't get out of bounds of an array.